# Find item in object array with same property

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array of objects like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 12.09.2015
            [title] =>  Testtitle3          
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 01.01.2015
            [title] =>  Testtitle3           
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [date] => 12.09.2015
            [title] =>  Testtitle3         
        )
}
```

now i wantr loop trough the arrays (with foreach) to check if a date is duplicated entry. If so put duplicates in new array to have a output like this (example with 12.09.2015 - cos this is a duplicate in my example array):

{12.09.2015 - title1:Testtitle3, title2:Testtitle3}

so basically the script should find duplicate dates in object array and echo them with both titles(same but dosent matter) and one date.

I tried something like this, but it doesnt work:

```
foreach($array as &$item){
    foreach($array as &$itemCheck){
    if($item->date === $itemCheck->date){
    echo '{' . $item->date . ' - ' .    $item->title . ',' . $itemCheck->title . '}';
    }
    }
}
```

im frustrated :) can u help me again guys? thx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the date in a variable

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->date, $temp)) {
       echo '{' . $item->date . ' - ' .    $item->title . ',' . $itemCheck->title . '}';
    } else {
        $temp[] = $item->date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $item){
    if (isset($helper){
        foreach($helper as $helperitem){
              if($item->date === $helperitem->date){
                 echo '{' . $item->date . ' - ' .    $item->title . ',' . $helperitem->title . '}';

              }
        }
    }
    $helper[]=$item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse the array, and then you can check in a second loop.

```
$colapsedArray = array();
foreach($array as &$item){
    $colapsedArray[$item['date']][] = $item['title'];
} unset($item); //else you can have strange side effects in PHP

foreach($colapsedArray as &$item) {
   if (count($item) > 1) {
      //echo item
   }
} unset($item);
```

After collapsing the `$collapsedArray` should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [12.09.2015] => Array
        (
            'Testtitle3',  
            'Testtitle3'  
        )

    [01.01.2015] => Array
        (
            'Testtitle3'           
        )
)
```

Comment: that's a great solution too! more flexibility and im able to access all data from both arrays! thx mate!